# Rank of $X$, with corresponding projection matrix $P_X$

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, projection-matrices

Must I assume $X$ has full rank in order to have a projection matrix $P_X$?

I understand that in order to have

$$P_X=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$$

or, more specifically, $(X^TX)^{-1}$, $X$ must have full rank. But what can I say about $X$ otherwise? Can't it be projected?

Comment: Full rank is for square matrices. $X$ does not need to be square.

Comment: Yeah I know, I meant of rank n less than p for example.

Comment: What are $n$ and $p$?

Comment: sorry I'll try writing it again. Let's say p is the rank of the matrix and the number of columns. n is the number of rows such that p is less than n

Comment: If $X$ has full column rank, then $X^\top X$ is invertible. I suppose that was your question.

Comment: Sorry got confused. I'm not at my best today. Rank is less than p